# How to create a very complicated route with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I have 4 models: School, Class, Student, Address. I want to build an API like `/api/schools/1/classes/2/students/3/address`.

This example would return the address of student which has id 3, belongs to class 2 and school 1 (may be more complicated in the future).

In Java it can be done easily:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/schools/{school-id}/classes/{class-id}/students/{student-id}/address")
public Address getAddressOf(path parameters) {
    return myService.doLookup(parameters);
}
```

But with DRF I don't even have any knowledge about how to achieve it since I'm very new to Python and DRF.

For now I just can write 4 `ModelViewset` corresponding with 4 models listed above to have very basic CRUD endpoints. How can I create my expected API?

Comment: So `student-id` is not a PK and the same `student-id` can exist in a different school and/or class and would have different address? Student address depends on school and class, right? If not then why not to handle `/api/students/{student-id}` endpoint for this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I would like to make the api as I described since I want to learn something so that I can apply to some projects in the near future. Again thank you

Comment: Given that you want to learn this and you are aware what @IvanStarostin is talking about, then you can have a look at DRF nested routers to achieve this:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers